# Does Visual Studio 2017 need an explicit move constructor declaration?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, move-constructor

The below code can be compiled successfully using Visual Studio 2015, but it failed using Visual Studio 2017. Visual Studio 2017 reports:

> error C2280: “std::pair::pair(const std::pair &)”: attempting to reference a deleted function

#### Code

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

struct Node
{
  std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> map_;
  // Uncommenting the following two lines will pass Visual Studio 2017 compilation
  //Node(Node&& o) = default;
  //Node() = default;
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<Node> vec;
  Node node;
  vec.push_back(std::move(node));
  return 0;
}
```

It looks like Visual Studio 2017 explicit needs a move constructor declaration. What is the reason?

Comment: You're missing `#include <vector>` but as far as I can tell, that code should compile (and it does on e.g. GCC 8.2). Do you have the latest and greatest VS2017?

Comment: I can confirm this code fails with error code under vs2017 15.4.2.

Comment: @rubenvb <unordered_map> will include <vector> internally

Comment: @DanielLangr, @Oliv, @Evg are all right. Looking into Vs2017's vector sourcecode, either `vec.push_back` or `vec.reserve` both call into `_Umove_if_noexcept` that internally call `_Uninitialized_copy` decided by `disjunction_v<is_nothrow_move_constructible<_Ty>, negation<is_copy_constructible<_Ty>>>`

Comment: @finn that is entirely implementation defined and factually untrue for e.g. GCC’s  libstdc++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at the `std::vector` source code (I replaced `pointer` and `_Ty` with actual types):

```
void _Umove_if_noexcept1(Node* First, Node* Last, Node* Dest, true_type)
    {   // move [First, Last) to raw Dest, using allocator
    _Uninitialized_move(First, Last, Dest, this->_Getal());
    }

void _Umove_if_noexcept1(Node* First, Node* Last, Node* Dest, false_type)
{   // copy [First, Last) to raw Dest, using allocator
    _Uninitialized_copy(First, Last, Dest, this->_Getal());
}

void _Umove_if_noexcept(Node* First, Node* Last, Node* Dest)
{   // move_if_noexcept [First, Last) to raw Dest, using allocator
    _Umove_if_noexcept1(First, Last, Dest,
        bool_constant<disjunction_v<is_nothrow_move_constructible<Node>, negation<is_copy_constructible<Node>>>>{});
}
```

If `Node` is *no-throw move-constructible* or is *not copy-constructible*, `_Uninitialized_move` is called, otherwise, `_Uninitialized_copy` is called.

The problem is that the type trait `std::is_copy_constructible_v` is `true` for `Node` if you do not declare a move constructor explicitly. This declaration makes copy-constructor deleted.

libstdc++ implements `std::vector` in a similar way, but there `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Node>` is `true` in contrast to MSVC, where it is `false`. So, move semantics is used and the compiler does not try to generate the copy-constructor.

But if we force `is_nothrow_move_constructible_v` to become `false`

```
struct Base {
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base&) = default;
    Base(Base&&) noexcept(false) { }
};

struct Node : Base {
    std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> map;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Node> vec;
    vec.reserve(1);
}
```

the same error occurs:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/ext/new_allocator.h:136:4: error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = std::unique_ptr<int>]’
  { ::new((void *)__p) _Up(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Im wondering as to why the issue is not seen with clang or gcc ?

Comment: @darune, the dumb answer is because gcc's and clang's implementations do not rely on `std::is_copy_constructible` in this particular piece of code. I don't have a better answer now.

Comment: If i understand you correctly that code is in the MSVC vector implementation (?) and isn't that a bug in this case ? It does feel like like a bug, because invoking the move constructor directly does compile fine.

Comment: @darune, yes, the code in my answer is directly from MSVC STL implementation. I agree that it feels like a bug.

Comment: @darune, added some info about in libstdc++.

Answer (score 9):

Minimal example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>>> vec;
  vec.reserve(1);
}
```

Live demo on GodBolt: https://godbolt.org/z/VApPkH.

---

Another example:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>> m;
auto m2 = std::move(m);              // ok
auto m3 = std::move_if_noexcept(m);  // error C2280
```

---

**UPDATE**

I believe the compilation error is legal. Vector's reallocation function can transfer (contents of) elements by using `std::move_if_noexcept`, therefore preferring copy constructors to throwing move constructors.

In libstdc++ (GCC) / libc++ (clang), move constructor of `std::unordered_map` is (seemingly) `noexcept`. Consequently, move constructor of `Node` is `noexcept` as well, and its copy constructor is not at all involved.

On the other hand, implementation from MSVC 2017 seemingly does not specify move constructor of `std::unordered_map` as `noexcept`. Therefore, move constructor of `Node` is not `noexcept` as well, and vector's reallocation function via `std::move_if_noexcept` tries to invoke copy constructor of `Node`.

Copy constructor of `Node` is implicitly defined such that is invokes copy constructor of `std::unordered_map`. However, the latter may not be invoked here, since the value type of map (`std::pair<const int, std::unique_ptr<int>>` in this case) is not copyable.

Finally, if you user-define move constructor of `Node`, its implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted. <s>And, IIRC, deleted implicitly declared copy constructor does not participate in overload resolution</s>. But, the deleted copy constructor is not considered by `std::move_if_noexcept`, therefore it will use throwing move constructor of `Node.`

Comment: Is this realy a bug? `std::is_copy_constructible_v<std::unordered_map<int, std::unique_ptr<int>>>` is true even if any attempt to copy such a type will result in a compilation error. Moreover it will also be detected as CopyInsertable, even if any try to instantiate the code to copy insert it will result in a compilation error.

Comment: @Oliv That's a good question. It seems that the problem is that the move constructor of `std::unordered_map` is not `noexcept` in MSVC 2017 (which is seemingly not required by the Standard, or is it?). In libstdc++/libc++, it is `noexcept`.

Comment: @Oliv I updated my answer, I guess you are right. I even don't think now that it is "surprising".

Comment: @Oliv Thanks for clarificaton, I rephrased my answer not to mention _CopyInsertable_ requirement. Important is, that `std::unordered_map` defines copy constructor, just it may not be invoked if the value type cannot be copied.

Comment: I think that we have excavated a rule to apply when we will use concepts. That is to make sure that the interface of a type really reflects its requirements. For example here the copy constructor of the unordered_map should have a constraint `requires is_copy_constructible_v<element_type>` or equivalent. I don't know how to name it, maybe rule *concept propagation rule* or maybe *concept explicity rule* ...??

Comment: Going to the standard, [`std::unordered_map`s move constructor](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/unord.map.overview) is not declared as `noexcept`. IIUC, if libstdc++ or libc++ mark it as `noexcept`, that's a bug in libstdc++ or libc++

Comment: @Justin In MSVC 2017, static assertion for `std::is_nothrow_move_constructible` applied to `std::unordered_map` fails: https://godbolt.org/z/Fkdflp. The very same static assertion with GCC/Clang doesn't fail. For instance, in libstdc++ the move constructor is defined as `unordered_map(unordered_map&&) = default;`. Underlying `__umap_hashtable` seems to have `noexcept` move constructor. In libstdc++ the move constructor is `noexcept` conditionally. BTW are you sure that adding `noexcept` to move constructors of Standard library types violate rules of the Standard C++?

Comment: @Oliv Concepts would be great here. However, even without concepts, it would be possible do "disable" copy constructor of a container if it's value type is not copy-constructible. Just I am not sure whether this would be Standard-compliant.

Comment: @DanielLangr I asked in the CppLang slack. It turns out that strengthening `noexcept` is compliant.

Comment: Adding `noexcept` is allowed: [\[res.on.exception.handling\] paragraph 5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conforming#res.on.exception.handling-5)

Comment: It may be allowed, but it's not helpful, as it results in code that works in one standards-conforming compiler to not work in another standards-conforming compiler, thereby making the standard less useful.

Comment: @Miral The Standard effectively says that it is _unspecified_ whether the move constructor of `std::unordered_map` is or isn't `noexcept`. If you write/use a code that requires it to be `noexcept`, you restrict its usage only for implementations that satisfy this condition. BTW, it's not at all about compilers, it's a matter of Standard Library implementations.

Answer (score 6):

When you declare a move constructor, the implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted. On the other hand, when you don't declare a move constructor, the compiler implicitly defines the copy constructor when it need it. And this implicit definition is ill-formed.

`unique_ptr` is not `CopyInsertable` in a container that uses a standard allocator because it is not copy constructible so the copy constructor of `map_` is ill-formed (it could have been declared as deleted, but this is not required by the standard).

As your example code show us, with newer version of MSVC, this ill-formed definition is generated with this example code. I do not think there is something in the standard that forbids it (even if this is realy surprising).

So you should indeed ensure that the copy constructor of Node is declared or implicitly defined as deleted.

Comment: Im wondering as to why the issue is not seen with clang or gcc ?

Comment: @darune because the generation of the code of the copy constructor is only performed when needed. So the error does not appear within this small example but it may in a larger piece of code.

Comment: i was aware of that - somehow it *feels* like  a bug in MSVC even though it might not be.. I mean if you invoke the move constructor directly (Node b(std::move(a)) ) it compiles in MSVC so why is the push_back with move (which actually turns into a emplace_back(std::move(xx))) ) not able to that when a direct move is ? possible a (cornercase) perfect forwarding issue (?)

Comment: @darune I think the bug is in the standard requirement. If a standard type is not copy constructible it should be possible to check it with traits. But actually implementing such a requirement would be a real pain. I hope that with concepts this will be fixed.

Comment: I don't have VS2017 accessible, but couldn't be the problem with that implicitly-declared move constructor of `std::unordered_map` (and therefore of `Node`) is not `noexcept`? Then, `push_back`, i.e., `emplace_back`, may prefer copy constructor (during reallocation) than potentially throwing move constructor (`std::move_if_noexcept`)? With user-declared move constructor, the copy constructor is deleted, so throwing move constructor will be used.

Comment: @DanielLangr Indeed that must be the reason why it generates the code of the ill-formed copy constructor.

Comment: The type traits magic to do this "correctly" is surprisingly complex. I implemented an open addressing hash map (and set) that is mostly API-compatible with `unordered_map`, and ended up having to use private inheritance from `std::conditional<std::is_copy_constructible<...>::value && ..., AllowCopy, DisallowCopy>::type` where `AllowCopy` is empty and `DisallowCopy` has deleted copy operations (among other things). I also check for default c'tible allocator, and all of this is still not quite right, e.g. I support neither allocator propagation on copy nor copying of elements in the allocator.

Comment: `is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Node>` is `false` in MSVC, so it tries to copy and fails; it is `true` in gcc, so it moves. If `is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Node>` is forced to become `false` in gcc, it also tries to copy and fails. Why do MSVC and gcc disagree on `is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<Node>` value?

Comment: @Evg And `is_copy_constructible<Node>` is true even if it is not possible to copy it! It is true because `is_copy_constructible_v<unordered_map<int,std::unique_ptr...>>` is true, while it should be required to be false by the standard. Then what happen if you check is_nothrow_copy_constructible is just chaos.

Answer (score 0):

**Visual Studio 2017:**

As @Evg indicated, the Visual Studio 2017's vector sourcecode finally call into _Uninitialized_copy because the implicitly-declared move constructor of Node is considered as not-nothrow (`is_nothrow_move_constructible<Node>` is false) and `is_copy_constructible<Node>` is true in Visual Studio 2017.

1) About `is_nothrow_move_constructible<Node>`:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor says:

> The implicitly-declared (or defaulted on its first declaration) move constructor has an exception specification as described in [dynamic exception specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/except_spec) (until C++17)[exception specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec) (since C++17)

Maybe it's reasonable to consider `is_nothrow_move_constructible<Node>` as false beacause `Node`'s data member `std::unordered_map`'s move constructor is not marked as noexcept.

2) About `is_copy_constructible<Node>`:

As @Oliv says, it's seemingly not logical to compute `is_copy_constructible<Node>` as true, specially considering the fact that `Node` is not copy_constructible has been detected and reported as compile error by Visual Studio 2017 compiler. `Node` is not copy_constructible beacause `std::unique_ptr` is not copy_constructible.

**Visual Studio 2015:**

Visual Studio 2015's vector has a different implemetation. `vec.push_back`->`_Reserve`->`_Reallocate`->`_Umove`->`_Uninitialized_move_al_unchecked`->`_Uninitialized_move_al_unchecked1`->`std::move(node)`. `is_nothrow_move_constructible<Node>` and `is_copy_constructible<Node>` are not involved. It just call `std::move(node)` instead of copy constructor. So the sample code can be compiled successfully using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: The important conclusion here is IMHO that MSVC 2017 is Standard-compliant. It's move constructor of `std::unordered_map` is not `noexcept`, which is perfectly fine. It's copy constructor is defined (must be), even if it cannot be used for non-copyable _value type_. There is nothing wrong with this implementation. This is how C++ Standard is written. Hopefully, with _concepts_, we will have much more control here over corresponding stuff.